# PyQt4 QPalette not working

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qpalette

```
    {btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Button', self)

    palettes = btn.palette()
    palettes.setColor(btn.backgroundRole(),QtCore.Qt.green)

    btn.setPalette(palettes)
    btn.setAutoFillBackground(True)}
```

Using `btn.backgroundRole()` only provides green border to the button.
Using `btn.foregroundRole()` changes the text color of the button
Using `btn.windowRole()` gives me error

> TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
>   
>   QPalette.setColor(QPalette.ColorGroup, QPalette.ColorRole, QColor):
>   argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
>   
>   QPalette.setColor(QPalette.ColorRole, QColor): argument 1 has
>   unexpected type 'str'

Tried `QtGui.QPalette.Background` in place of `btn.windowRole()` but does nothing
Also tried `QtGui.QPalette.Base` but does nothing
And also `QtGui.QPalette.Window` does nothing

How can I change button color using palettes?
I am unable to rectify the problem. I am using windows 7, PyQt4 and Python 3.4

Comment: Don't know about PyQt4, but these are `enums` at C++. Maybe a problem with PyQt? Could you try to update PyQt? (I'm not of much help beyond this since I'm not a Python programmer...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read in Qt documentation about `QPalette` :

> Warning: Some styles do not use the palette for all drawing, for
>   instance, if they make use of native theme engines. This is the case
>   for both the Windows XP, Windows Vista, and the Mac OS X styles.

Windows 7 style also does not use palette colors for buttons. You should use stylesheets to give a color to your button. If you use some other theme than Windows 7 style, you can use `QPalette.Button` role to change the button color.