# "Blinking" buttons in PyQT5

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, qpushbutton, qpropertyanimation

Here's the deal: I'm trying to make button A "blink" when button B is pushed, and the blinking should then stop when the user pushes button A. Furthermore, button A should then go back to its former state.

After long reading through the documentation and other questions at SO, I have now following piece of code:

**Python 2.7**

```
class Widget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Widget, self).__init__()

        self.resize(300,200)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)


        self.button_stop = QPushButton("Stop")
        layout.addWidget(self.button_stop)

        self.button_start = QPushButton("Start", self)
        layout.addWidget(self.button_start)

        self.animation = QPropertyAnimation(self, "color", self)
        self.animation.setDuration(1000)
        self.animation.setLoopCount(100)
        self.animation.setStartValue(self.color)
        self.animation.setEndValue(self.color)
        self.animation.setKeyValueAt(0.1, QColor(0,255,0))

        self.button_start.clicked.connect(self.animation.start)
        self.button_stop.clicked.connect(lambda: self.stop())

    def stop(self):
        self.animation.stop()
        self.button_stop.setStyleSheet("")

    def getColor(self):
        return self.button_stop.palette().base()

    def setColor(self, color):
        palette = self.button_stop.palette()
        palette.setColor(self.button_stop.backgroundRole(), color)
        self.button_stop.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.button_stop.setPalette(palette)


    color = pyqtProperty(QColor, getColor, setColor)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```

The code itself I got mostly from @Alexander Lutsenko in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31786684/blinking-widget-with-pyqt?) question, with a few modifications here and there to test my needs. The main part ist straightforward: I create a window with two `QPushButton`, one to start the `QPropertyAnimation` and the other one to stop it. The `QPropertyAnimation` itself is applied to one of the buttons. It should in theory change the background color of the button, but due to the limitations explained in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28257482/pyqt4-qpalette-not-working) it only provides a colorful border to the `QPushButton`. And I'm fine with that, it doesn´t look that intrusive.

**The problem**

After starting the animation, if I push the `Stop` button, the button doesn't go back to its original state (with no colorful border), but stays with the color of the animation at the time the `Stop` button was pressed.

Furthermore, I get following warning:

`TypeError: unable to convert a Python 'QBrush' object to a C++ 'QColor' instance`

But the script keeps running and the animation going, so that doesn't break anything.

**The question**

How do I "reset" the styleSheet of the button properly? Is there another (maybe better and pythonic) way to do the blinking button stuff? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property does not save the initial state so even if you pair the animation it will not be restored to the initial state. So the solution in this case is to save that state in a variable and create a `reset_color()` method that restores the color again..

On the other hand the error message: `TypeError: unable to convert to Python 'QBrush' object to a C ++ 'QColor' instance` indicates that the code `self.button_stop.palette().base()` returns a `QBrush`, but it is expected a `QColor`, and there is no conversion implied, so that implementation must be changed.

As a matter of order I will create a new class that inherits from `QPushButton` and implement those properties.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class BlinkButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QPushButton.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.default_color = self.getColor()

    def getColor(self):
        return self.palette().color(QPalette.Button)

    def setColor(self, value):
        if value == self.getColor():
            return
        palette = self.palette()
        palette.setColor(self.backgroundRole(), value)
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.setPalette(palette)

    def reset_color(self):
        self.setColor(self.default_color)

    color = pyqtProperty(QColor, getColor, setColor)


class Widget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Widget, self).__init__()

        self.resize(300,200)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.button_stop = BlinkButton("Stop")
        layout.addWidget(self.button_stop)

        self.button_start = QPushButton("Start", self)
        layout.addWidget(self.button_start)

        self.animation = QPropertyAnimation(self.button_stop, "color", self)
        self.animation.setDuration(1000)
        self.animation.setLoopCount(100)
        self.animation.setStartValue(self.button_stop.default_color)
        self.animation.setEndValue(self.button_stop.default_color)
        self.animation.setKeyValueAt(0.1, QColor(0,255,0))

        self.button_start.clicked.connect(self.animation.start)
        self.button_stop.clicked.connect(self.stop)

    def stop(self):
        self.animation.stop()
        self.button_stop.reset_color()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```